# Twitter bootstrap - prepended input elements overlapping when placed next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textinput

I'm trying to put two input elements next to each other, with a prepended item on the first input, using display:table styles. However, this results in the second input element overlapping the first. I've tried using box-sizing: border-box with no luck. It seems like the problem is that I'm constraining the width of the parent div and then setting the width of the input element to 100% so that it fills up the parent, but this doesn't work at all. Here is a JSfiddle example:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">HI</span>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="number"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pgPY/7/

The goal is to get a bunch of rows like the above where each instance of the text input has some label which might not be the same width, so I need some way to make sure that the text inputs all line up. Maybe I should just give up on using the prepended element and use a separate div for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see where the problem comes from. Anyways, that worked for me:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 200px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    margin-right: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the margin-right being added does work, I think this might be the proper solution.

Comment: Even if it works in this case, I'm not sure if it's more of a workaround than a general solution...

Comment: Yeah, it is a workaround, but it's more sane than the other solution. Although I'm really tempted for this application to do something extreme and hide the input fields and do some trickery with mirroring the contents into a div, because sizing and positioning them is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have not used the input-prepend class in the second input , you should write it as follows

```
<div class="cell input-prepend">
        <input type="number"/>
    </div>
```

And in css remove width=100% from input and use margin-right

```
    input[type=text] {
       margin-right:10px;

      }
```

Can you please check the JSfidlle [updated JSfiddle prepend](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/mh3hH/22/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
    </form>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need them to be next to each other, did you miss that part of the question or am I missing something? Oh it depends on the width of my browser... I don't want that actually, and I don't see how you would stack multiple rows of this, so I don't think this solves it.

Comment: Oh hmm I guess multiple rows does work but I'm not sure I understand why. See, when you try to constrain the width of the first input's container is how you get the situation I was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/mh3hH/19/

Comment: See thats because the browser is resizing , and to make it fit the visible area they all get stacked up that way .. wat you can do is write media queries and than rearrange them accordingly and the situation will be resolved for sure .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24653/discussion-between-shail-and-ibrahim)